# Access activemq Poolable Connection factory as OSGI service

Tags: activemq-classic, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix, blueprint-osgi, fuseesb

I am using fuse 6.0 and activemq 5.8. Instead of defining activemq poolable connection factory in each bundle, it makes sense to define in a common bundle and expose it as osgi service. I created blue print file in FUSE_HOME/etc and opened an osgi service like this.

```
  <osgix:cm-properties id="prop" persistent-id="xxx.xxx.xxx.properties" /> 

    <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL" value="${xxx.url}" />
            <property name="userName" value="${xxx.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="${xxx.password}" />
        </bean>

<bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="${maxconnections}" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<service ref="pooledConnectionFactory" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"> 
    <service-properties> 
        <entry key="name" value="localhost"/> 
    </service-properties> 
</service>
```

and when i try to access this service in both blueprint files and spring text files like this

```
<reference id="pooledConnectionFactory" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"/>
bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledConnectionFactory"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="${xxx.concurrentConsumers}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig"/>
    </bean>
```

but I am getting following expection during bundles startup.

Failed to add Connection ID:PLNL6237-55293-1401929434025-11:1201, reason: java.lang.SecurityException: User name [null] or password is invalid.

I even defined compendium definition in my bundles.

How can i solve this problem? any help is appreciated.
I found this online https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/SM-2183
Do i need to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're using the property placeholders incorrectly.  First of all, you should know what osgix:cm-properties only exposes the properties at the persistent id that you specify.  You can treat it like a java.util.Properties object, and even inject it into a bean as one.  This does however mean that it makes no attempt to resolve the properties.

To resolve properties, use spring's property placeholder configurer.

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="properties" ref="prop"/>
 </bean>
```

P.S.  The persistent id of cm-properties is the name of the file, not including the file type.  You don't need the .properties at the end.